# why does eval mess up printf '\n', and where to find info on eval

Tags: bash

I had a previous question with bash `eval`, the responder confirmed to me I have to use `eval` in that case.

The manual on `eval` says - that's all it says I am afraid -

> eval [arguments]
>
> The arguments are concatenated together into a single command, which is then read and executed, and its exit status returned as the exit status of eval. If there are no arguments or only empty arguments, the return status is zero.

Now I have this problem:

```
bash> printf '\n'

bash> eval printf '\n'
nbash>
```

Why is that?  Why does eval (which I have to use, not in this case of SSCCE, but in the real case) damage the effect of printf ?

I wish the manual said more about how bash and eval behave.  Where did the previous responder find all that information, seemingly more than what the manual says (as I shown above).

OK, the responder suggested the quote.  Great, but now I really need this

```
bash> printf "foo bar"'\n'
```

to work with eval.  If I do

```
bash eval "printf foo bar'\n'"
```

does not work as before

Comment: All right I just need to escape the double quotes it looks like.  Thank you all everybody, this is great help, I appreciate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
eval printf '\n'
```

The shell reads this command as three words: `eval`, `printf` and `\n`. The single quotes don’t exist anymore after parsing these words.

The `eval` command now gets this to evaluate: `printf \n`, and, since the backslash is not enclosed in quotes, it is just discarded. Therefore this is equivalent to:

```
eval printf n
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the actual command you get to evaluate:

```
# echo printf '\n'
printf \n
```

And this is the result of your evaluated command:

```
# printf \n
n
```

Answer (score 1):

echo is your friend!!

Replace the eval by echo to "see" what is being executed:

```
$ echo printf '\n'
printf '\n'
```

What will happen with that command?, try it:

```
$ printf \n
n
```

As the value is not quoted it lost its special meaning to printf.

So, in the end, the problem is one of quoting (as always is with eval).

```
$ eval printf \''done %s\n'\' \'test\'
done test
```